# Cookie-based vs Session vs Token-based vs Claims-based authentications

Tags: authentication

I have read about authentications and become confusing about types classification.

Let's start from Cookie-based authentication, If I understand it right, the key point is that all data, needed for user authentication, is stored in cookies. And this is my first confusion: in cookies we may store

- session id and so it becomes a Session-based authentication?
- claims, and so should it be called as a Claims-based authentication?
- I have found that some people even store JWT token in cookies, but this seems like a custom implementation of own auth flow...

Now let's switch to Claims-based authentication. The main element is the claim and the collection of claims could use as container

- cookies (as discussed above)
- token (JWT as the example).

From the other side, when we are talking about the token, it may contain any kind of information... Session Id for example...

So what have I missed? Why don't people define something like `Cookie-Session-based` or `Token-Claims-based` authentications when talking about authentication types?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I agree that the naming of the different concepts is confusing. When talking about authentication in a web context, there are several aspects to consider.

## What information does the client send when authenticating?

- **A session id**. This means that the server has a session storage which contains the active sessions. Sessions are *stateful* on the server side.
- **A set of claims**. Claims contain information on what operations the client may perform. The server does not keep track of each authenticated client, but trusts the claims. Claims are typically *stateless* on the server side.

## How does the client send the authentication information?

- **Cookies**. Browsers send cookies automatically with each request, after the cookie has been set. Cookies are vulnerable to XSRF.
- **Other headers**. Typically, the Authorization header is used for this. These headers are not send by the browser automatically, but have to be set by the client. This is vulnerable to XSS.
- **Request Url**. The authentication information is included in the URL. This is not commonly used.

## What is the format of the authentication information?

- **Plain, unsigned text**. This can be used for session ids. A session id is generally not guessable by the client, so the server can trust that the client has not forged it.
- **Json Web Token**. JWTs are cryptographically signed and contain expiry information. The client can usually decode the token, but cannot alter it without the server noticing.
- **Any other signed format**. Same as JWTs. The important thing is the cryptographic signature, which prevents the client from altering the data.

## Bonus: How does the client store the information locally

- **Cookies**. This is of course the case when using cookies to transmit the information. But Cookies can also be used as just a client side storage mechanism. This requires the cookie to be readable from scripts to be useful. For example, a client could read the cookie with JavaScript and send the information with an Authorization-Header.
- **Local Storage**. This is often the only possible method, if cookies are unavailable. Requires management with JavaScript.

## What do people mean when they say...

- **"Cookie based authentication"**. I find that this usually means "Session id, send by cookie, possible as plain text."
- **"Token based authentication"**. Usually this means "Claims, send using the authentication header, encoded as a Json Web Token."
- **"Claims based authentication"**. Could be anything but a session id.

Comment: Excellent summary! One thing to note... All of these are also vulnerable to man in the middle attacks where a third party could hijack the cookie/header information, so be sure to send all traffic through HTTPS.

Comment: Excellent! So easy to understand

Answer (score 7):

Simply put,

1. **Cookie-Based Authentication**

   - Web-client (eg: web-browser) stores cookie sent by the web-server after successful authentication.
   - Cookie contains info about the user, client, authN timestamp and other useful data with unique-id to determine the cookie.
   - Typically, cookie is encrypted by the web-server with domain attribute set (eg: `google.com`) and send it across to the web-client.
   - Whenever the web-client wants to access the domain resource (eg: `mail.google.com`), it will send all cookie based on its domain (eg: `google.com`) to the web-server, which validates/ verifies and grant/ deny access based on state and timestamp of the cookie.
2. **Session-Based Authentication**

   - Along with the web-client cookie, if a web-server stores the user authN data in their back-end, then it will be called Session-based authentication.
   - This is very useful in the event of any breach that the web-client gained access to the system where it shouldn't get access, then from the back-end, the web-client's session can be revoked by the admin.
3. **Token-Based Authentication**

   - Generally this is used in non web-client scenarios, where there is no way to store cookie in the client side.
   - Hence, the web-server sends the signed token (contains info about user, client, authN timestamp and other useful data with unique-id) to the client after successful authentication.
   - Whenever, a client wants to access a resource, it need to send this token and web-server validates/ verifies the token before it allow to access the resource.
4. **Claims-Based Authentication**

   - This is same as token-based authentication, only that it add some more data into the token about the client and/or user associated to the client.
   - These data are pertain to authorization, which talks about what the client shall do within the resource (eg: mail.read, mail.delete, calendar.read).